# Why is the top SN2 reaction faster? (Molecular Orbital Theory)

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, reactivity, reaction-coordinate

I'm having trouble understanding why the top SN2 reaction proceeds faster. I know that benzylic and allylic halides react faster in SN2 reactions than non-conjugated halides. I think it's because the transition state is more stable but how can you explain that using MO Theory?

[image: m]

> This is what my professor drew for this question but I don't understand it all. Any help would be appreciated :)

[image: Why is the top SN2 reaction faster?]

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/why-do-allylic-halides-prefer-sn2-reaction-over-sn1